# Unable to make WCF calls from windows docker container

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding, windows-container

My docker file  -

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
USER ContainerAdministrator
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 9300\
COPY . .
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]

RUN powershell "C:\build.ps1"

# Install Windows components required for WCF service hosted on IIS
RUN Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-TCP-Activation45; `
    Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45; `
    Add-WindowsFeature Web-WebSockets; `
    Add-WindowsFeature RPC-over-HTTP-Proxy; `
    Add-WindowsFeature Simple-TCPIP; `
    Add-WindowsFeature MSMQ; `
    Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server; `
    Add-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET; `
    Add-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45; `
    Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*; `
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/servicemonitor/2.0.1.10/ServiceMonitor.exe -OutFile C:\ServiceMonitor.exe; 

ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat", "&&", "powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

I am using the sdk image (rather than wcf) image beacuse I need to run msbuild and vstest on my projects at build time.

When running the container, I use this -

```
docker run --rm -it -p 9200:9200/tcp -p 808:808/tcp -p 80:80 -p 443:443 image:latest
```

When I try to make WCF calls from inside the container I am seeing this error. The WCF service is not owned by me. The owner of the WCF service said there is no auth from his side. This error is instant, it does not await for timeout. This means, the call never left the container.

```
Exception details
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:02:59.9687380'. ---> System.IO.IOException: The write operation failed, see inner exception. ---> 
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:02:59.9687380'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.WriteNow(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, 
TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

This is my WCF client config -

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://x.x.x.x:9200/myservice.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_service" contract="myserice" name="name"></endpoint>
</client>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_service" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="100" maxBufferPoolSize="214748364" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="100" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I have been trying a lot of things but have not been successful. It looks like the calls are being blocked on the container. If I run the WCF client from my host (laptop), it works, since the container is running on my laptop, it should also be able to make the call.

Comment: I searched quite a few sources and I think this one will help you:[document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/docker)